# regex to match something that is 1+ chrs, but not 500 chrs

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-routes

I'm looking for a single regex expression that will match something that is 1 or more characters in length that does **not** match `500`. This is to be used in a Rails routes file, particularly to handle exceptions.

routes.rb

```
match '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'
match '/:anything', :to => "errors#not_found", :constraints => { :anything => /THE REGEX GOES HERE/ }
```

I'm a little lost on how to define regex that matches something and simultaneously does not match something else.

Comment: Since anything will be 0 or more characters in length, why can't you simply match things that are not 500?

Comment: You could simply use `(?m)^(?!500$).*$` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zT0sX5)

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. I meant to match things that are **one** ore more characters. Can you think of a way to do that without matching `500`?

Comment: @BradRice replace `*` with `+`:p

Comment: @BradRice Sorry, the `m` modifier in php is not the same as in ruby, try the following `\A(?!500\z).+\z` [demo1](http://rubular.com/r/v6eB29uX0J), [demo2](http://rubular.com/r/n5Pn887irl), [demo3](http://rubular.com/r/UkultjrXS5)

Comment: @HamZa that looks perfect! Add an answer for that and I'll accept it. In the answer, could you explain what the `?!` do? Is that like `not` for regex?

Comment: @BradRice I'll maybe do that later on, `a(?!b)` would match `a` not followed by `b`. So in your case `\A(?!500\z)` this means match begin of line not followed by `500\z`, `\z` means end of line.

Comment: @Jerry I'm more concerned with valid Rails routes here, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to check if a string doesn't contain the substring 500:

```
\A(?>[^5]++|5++(?!00))+\z
```

if you want to allow 5000 or 5500..., you can do this:

```
\A(?>[^5]++|5{2,}+|5(?!00(?!0)))+\z
```

First string explanation:

```
\A           # begining of the string
(?>          # opening of an atomic group
   [^5]++    # all characters but 5 one or more times (possessive)
  |          # OR
   5++(?!00) # one or more 5 not followed by 00
)+           # closing of the atomic group, one or more times
\z           # end of the string
```

[Possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) are here to avoid regex engine backtracks for better performances (the regex fails quickly).

Answer (score 1):

Rails routes are matched in the order that they appear in routes.rb. By putting `/500` first (or higher up) in the list, it guarantees that the routes further down do not match `/500`. You shouldn't have to worry about this.

So, instead, split this into more routes.

```
match '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'
match '.*500.*', to: 'somewhere else'
match '/:anything', :to => "errors#not_found"
```

and don't worry about the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that Regex? Your route definition

`match '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'`

will catch all those `/500` requests and it means that your next route rule

`match '/:anything', :to => "errors#not_found"`

won't get them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this regex should do the job `\A(?!500\z).+\z`.

**Explanation**

- `\A` : match begin of line
- `(?!500\z)` : negative lookahead, which means check if there is no 500 + end of line `\z`
- `.+` : match any character one or more times
- `\z` : match end of line